# How to solve System.OutOfMemoryException in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net

My code is

```
     private byte[] Invoke(Stream inputFileStream, CryptoAction action)
     {
        var msData = new MemoryStream();
        CryptoStream cs = null;

        try
        {
            long inputFileLength = inputFileStream.Length;
            var byteBuffer = new byte[4096];
            long bytesProcessed = 0;
            int bytesInCurrentBlock = 0;

            var csRijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
            switch (action)
            {
                case CryptoAction.Encrypt:
                    cs = new CryptoStream(msData, csRijndael.CreateEncryptor(this.Key, this.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    break;

                case CryptoAction.Decrypt:
                    cs = new CryptoStream(msData, csRijndael.CreateDecryptor(this.Key, this.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                    break;
            }

            while (bytesProcessed < inputFileLength)
            {
                bytesInCurrentBlock = inputFileStream.Read(byteBuffer, 0, 4096);
                cs.Write(byteBuffer, 0, bytesInCurrentBlock);
                bytesProcessed += bytesInCurrentBlock;
            }
            cs.FlushFinalBlock();

            return msData.ToArray();
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

In case of encrypting large files of size 60mb System.OutOfMemoryException is thrown and program crashes.My operating system is 64bit and have 8Gb of ram.

Comment: That exception is called [`OutOfMemoryException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.outofmemoryexception.aspx) even if `MemoryOutOfException` would be better.

Comment: Hahaha. In which line are you getting it?

Comment: In  cs.FlushFinalBlock();

Comment: I believe this is related to the internal buffers used by the stream, not sure though

Comment: How much memory does your process use when it crashes? Are you running it as a 64-bit process?

Comment: Sidenote: Your crypto is probably unsafe because you are using unauthenticated encryption.

Comment: Ram goes above 4Gb because i am reading many files

Comment: So you are reading many files. That is of course relevant to this question! You are getting out of memory because the files that you read exceed available memory in total.

Comment: But i am reading one file at a time and then dispose them

Comment: OutOfMemoryException is one of the most misunderstood exception classes.  To clarify, it doesn't mean that your system is out of memory - it means that the system could not find a free *continuous*  spot in memory to hold the object you want to instantiate.

Comment: You aren't disposing your streams.. `CryptoStream` and `MemoryStream` should both be within `using()` blocks or calling `Dispose` within a finally block to ensure that their allocated memory is released for garbage collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to get rid of all that buffer management code, that could be the cause of your problems... try to work with two streams (MemoryStream for volatile output is good):

```
using (FileStream streamInput = new FileStream(fileInput, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (FileStream streamOutput = new FileStream(fileOutput, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write))
    {
        CryptoStream streamCrypto = null;
        RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
        cspRijndael.BlockSize = 256;

        switch (CryptoAction)
        {
            case CryptoAction.ActionEncrypt:
                streamCrypto = new CryptoStream(streamOutput, rijndael.CreateEncryptor(this.Key, this.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                break;

            case CryptoAction.ActionDecrypt:
                streamCrypto = new CryptoStream(streamOutput, rijndael.CreateDecryptor(this.Key, this.IV), CryptoStreamMode.Write);
                break;
        }

        streamInput.CopyTo(streamCrypto);
        streamCrypto.Close();
    }
}
```